# My $resource query is returning all the objects when I have parameters for just one _id

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to find just the store that matches my id parameter. In terminal everything looks fine:

```
GET /admin/company?_id=5470e913d20b3dab7c13218b 200 219.590 ms - -
```

And then here's my $resource

```
angular.module('mean.management').factory('Companies', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/admin/company/:companyId', {
            companyId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            get: {method: 'GET',isArray: true}
        });
    }
]);
```

It's searching with the right _id but it returns a list of a bunch of companies instead of just the one company.

Here's the controller

```
    $scope.newStore = function () {
        Companies.get({
            _id: $scope.global.user.company // _id works fine
        }, function (company2) {

            console.log(company2); // this logs 40 different companies when it should be one matching the _id
        });

    };
```

If I replace Companies.get with Companies.query, it's the same problem. Doesn't change anything. I also changed get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false} instead of true, and that just returns an error in the browser console (because it's an array).

Update: I know the parameter is correct because if I go to localhost:3000/admin/company?_id=5470e913d20b3dab7c13218b and ctrl+f 5470e913d20b3dab7c13218b I can see the object with that _id in it.

Update2: I think I'm getting closer to a solution. If I comment out this, it doesn't return any articles

```
// routes
app.get('/admin/company', companies.all); // if I comment this, it won't return anything
app.get('/admin/company/:companyId', companies.oneCompany); // this doesn't seem to be doing anything
```

Update3
Here are some examples of server-side code

```
exports.oneCompany = function(req, res, next, id) {
  Company.load(id, function(err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
    req.article = article;

        res.json(req.article);
    next();
  });
};
```

Here's another one I tried

```
exports.company1 = function (req, res, next, id) {
    Company
        .findOne({
            _id: id
        })
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return next(new Error('Failed to load User ' + id));
            req.profile = user;
            res.json(user);
            next();
        });
};
```

Comment: You should be aware that it is not the $resource that is returning results, but the server. Therefore, you should get some insight into what is happening on the server side. Do you have access to server code?

Comment: Just added two server side examples that I tried that didn't work.

Comment: Figured it out... have no idea how. I'll write a solution below when I simplify the code/variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly new to ngresource myself and figured similar things out last week my self. Your issue here is the resource definition where you generate the companyId into URL path but not as parameter when you define the resouce like this:

```
return $resource('/admin/company/:companyId', {
   companyId: '@_id'
},
```

What you would need is just simply this:

```
return $resource('/admin/company')
```

And use this $resource as

```
app.get({_id:companies.oneCompany});
```

This generates resource URLs as /admin/company?_id=XYZ. This part is documented in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource as paramDefaults:

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template
>   if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search
>   query after the ?.
>
> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet',
>   salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello.

Hope this helps.